# SceneKit change color of materials programmatically

Tags: scenekit, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

My googling skills have failed me on this one so if this is an obvious question please forgive me.

I am trying to create one of those typical rpg character creation screens. I have a model, I have base diffuse maps, and let's say I want to change the model's hair color. I can set the diffuse to a different color (instead of the diffuse texture) and it works but it loses all those small details. For example, if I were to change the eyes, they would just be a solid color.

Is there a correct way to go about editing these colors? Is there something I specifically need in my diffuse maps? Another texture? etc?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please file more details and description of your issue. Can you show some code you have already?

Answer (score 0):

After researching how general textures work I solved my issue and maybe this will help others:

Inside SceneKit you get to choose a Diffuse, Emission, Normal, etc for textures. If you choose a specific color for the diffuse you'll lose any sort of texture/material/detail of that texture because it's a solid color. For example, if you were making a coin model, and the head of the coin was in your diffuse; changing the diffuse to a solid color will give you a solid colored coin with no detail. The way I solved this was adding a normal map with the details.

With the normal map, you can change the diffuse to a solid color, and the details of the models are showed through the normal map; resulting in any color coin.